# Script add dynamically didnt working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with datetime script as per below:

```js
function createLabour(){ 
     var cnt2 = '<tr class="noprint"><td><div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="2017-05-16T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1"><input class="form-control" style="width: 200px" type="text" name="st_datetime[]" value="" readonly><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span></div></td><td><div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="2017-05-16T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1"><input class="form-control" style="width: 200px" type="text" name="en_datetime[]" value="" readonly><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span></div></td>';
        var d2 = document.getElementById('frm2');
     d2.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',cnt2);
     }
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="frm2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><b>Start Date/Time</b></th>
      <th><b>End Date/Time</b></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
     <div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="2017-05-16T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
        <input class="form-control" style="width: 200px" type="text" name="en_datetime[]" value="" readonly>
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
      </div>
     </td>
     <td>
       <div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="2017-05-16T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
        <input class="form-control" style="width: 200px" type="text" name="en_datetime[]" value="" readonly>
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
       </div>
       </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr><td colspan="9"><input type="button" value="Add More" class="noprint" onclick="createLabour()"></td></tr>
</table>
```

For first table it work well, while when pressing add more button the second table will not work.

Comment: Your HTML isn't valid: there is no opening `<table>` tag for second table.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? What libraries are you using ? what is not working ? what is supposed to work ?

Comment: Please don't use tags that aren't relevant to your question. PHP and CSS have nothing to do with this. I've removed them for you this time. But keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to target `<tbody>`, not `<table>`. If you add an ID to the `tbody` and use that in the selector, it should work.

Also, you don't have an opening tab for the second table.